# Highcharts: Line graph with half solid line and half dotted line?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to show a time series line graph in highcharts - to the left of center is historical data, so the line needs to be solid.  To the right of center is predicted data, so the line needs to be dotted or dashed.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can, using [zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.areasplinerange.zones). Zones let you apply different styles within the same series of data, and can be applied against both x- and y-axes.

### Examples

1. [Different colors by y-axis value](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
      zones: [{
        value: 0,
        color: '#f7a35c',
        style: 'dotted',
      }, {
        value: 10,
        color: '#7cb5ec'
      }, {
        color: '#90ed7d'
      }, ]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

2. [Different dash styles by x-axis position](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-dashstyle-dot/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Zone with dash style'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Dotted line typically signifies prognosis'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
      zoneAxis: 'x',
      zones: [{
        value: 8
      }, {
        dashStyle: 'dot'
      }]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't think you can have two different kind of line style in one series, but you can split the series into two, then specify the x coordinates for the second series to start where the first left off. Then you can set the `dashStyle` of that line.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [{x: 5, y: 21.5}, {x: 6, y: 22.0}, {x: 7, y: 24.8}, {x: 8, y: 24.1}, {x: 9, y: 20.1}, {x:10, y: 14.1}, {x:11, y: 13}],
            dashStyle: 'dash'
        }]
```

Here's a JSFiddle illustrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/mkremer90/zMZEV/1/

Comment: Thanks Matthew!  That's similar to what I did - with my first series, I did values of 1,2,3,4,null,null,null,null

With the second(dashed) series, I did null,null,null,null,5,6,7,8.

Comment: You can also look at the linkedTo option, http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.linkedTo. This will prevent two series from being displayed in the legend.

Comment: I need same capability but in stacked area chart. Two series will not work in that case. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. This is possible. Hard to picture your chart but what you could have is 2 series. One is your real data and the other is the predicted/future data. To set the line style use [`dashStyle`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.dashStyle).

Comment: a-ha- a second series - that's exactly what I needed to get started. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, how do you have the continuity between the point where your solid line ends and where your dotted line starts? In my case I have bigger steps so the graph looks broken when the transition of the series is shown.

Comment: @anshupitlia, it would depend on your use case. Put up a question with some representative code and we can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Yes solid and dashed lines in one line graph is possible .I have implemented it using a java program to create my data for series .

Create two series

```
series : [
                                        {
                                            name : 'Series 1',
                                            id : 'series1',
                                            data : mydashData,
                                            allowPointSelect : true,
                                            marker: {
                                                enabled: false
                                            }

                                        },
                                        {
                                            name : 'Series 2',
                                            data : myDotData,
                                            dashStyle : 'dot',
                                            id : 'series2',
                                            color : '#A81F40',
                                            allowPointSelect : true,
                                            marker: {
                                                enabled: false
                                            }

                                        }
}
```

Consider these points
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

From 1 -5 its dashed line .
From 5-10 its dotted Line .
From 10-15 its dashed line again .
Consider some sample X axis Values as you wish.

This is the java logic to create two series data points : -

```
List dashList;
List dotList;

Initial = FirstPoint ;

LOOP
if Initial == Dash and LastParsedPoint = Dash 
 add to DashList corresponding to that X axis value

if Initial ==Dot and LastParsePoint = Dot
 add to DotList corresponding to that X axis value

if Initial == Dot and LastParsePoint =Dash
 add to DashList Y and X values
 add to DashList y =NULL and same X value
 add to DotList  y and X value.

if Initial =Dash and LastParsePoint =Dot
 add to DotList  Y and X values
 add to DotList  Y =NULL and same X value
 add to DashList  Y and X value.


LastParsePoint =Initial

END LOOP.
```

Send this two list as json to Jsp or HTMl page and assign it to data of both the series .

Here is a sample i created .Please save this code in an HTMl file As Chart.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    //console.log(pathname);
    var containerName = 1;

    /*Creates a div element by passing index name and class*/
    function create_div_dynamic(i, id, className) {

        dv = document.createElement('div'); // create dynamically div tag
        dv.setAttribute('id', id + i); //give id to it
        dv.className = className; // set the style classname
        //set the inner styling of the div tag
        dv.style.margin = "0px auto";
        if (id == 'container') {
            //hr = document.createElement('hr');
            //br = document.createElement('br');//Break after Each Chart Container and Horizontal Rule.
            //document.body.appendChild(br);
            //document.body.appendChild(hr);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(dv);
    }

    /*Creates a span element by passing index name and class*/
    function create_span_dynamic(i, id, className) {

        dv = document.createElement('span'); // create dynamically div tag
        dv.setAttribute('id', id + i); //append id to to name
        dv.className = className; // set the style classname
        //set the inner styling of the span tag
        dv.style.margin = "0px auto";
        document.body.appendChild(dv);
    }


    /*Get URL Parameters*/
    function getUrlParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var json = getUrlParameter('json');
              $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: json,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (datas){
            //Each data table column/block index.
                var blockNumber = 0;
                //Each Row inside block index
                var rowNumber = 0;
                //Used to store previous charts row index for blank divs generation
                var prevRowNum=0;

                //Number of blank divs created .
                var oldC=0;

                //J : Chart Index
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    for ( var key in datas.root[j]) {
                        var solid = [];
                        var dot = [];

                        for (i = 0; i < datas.root[j][key][0].solid.length; i++) {
                            solid.push([parseInt(datas.root[j][key][0].solid[i].date),parseFloat(datas.root[j][key][0].solid[i].value)|| null ]);
                        }

                        for (i = 0; i < datas.root[j][key][0].dot.length; i++) {
                            dot.push([parseInt(datas.root[j][key][0].dot[i].date),parseFloat(datas.root[j][key][0].dot[i].value)|| null ]);
                        }
                        var chartBlock = '';

                        var k = j;

                        //Container Name
                        var renderCont = 'container'+ ++j;
                        create_div_dynamic(j,'container','image-capture-container');


                        //Creating Charts
                        this['chart_' + j] = new Highcharts.Chart(
                        {
                            chart : {
                                    renderTo : renderCont,
                                    type : 'line',
                                    zoomType : 'xy',
                                    borderWidth : 0,
                                    borderColor : '#ffffff',
                                    borderRadius : 0,
                                    width : 600,
                                    height : 400,

                                    plotShadow : false,
                                    alignTicks :true,
                                    plotBackgroundColor:'#C0C4C9',
                                    //margin: [15, 10, 40,60],
                                    style : {
                                            //position : 'relative',
                                            opacity : 100,
                                            textAlign : 'center'
                                            }
                                    },
                            xAxis : {
                                        useHTML : true,
                                        type : 'datetime',
                                        lineColor: '#ffffff',

                                        tickInterval:30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                                        tickColor: '#000000',
                                        tickWidth: 1,
                                        tickLength: 5
                                    },
                            yAxis : {
                                        title : {
                                                useHTML :'true',
                                                align : 'high',
                                                offset:0,
                                                rotation: 0,
                                                y: 1,
                                                x:-4,
                                                },
                                            lineWidth : 1,
                                            gridLineWidth :2,
                                            minorGridLineWidth : 1,
                                            gridLineColor :'#FFFFFF',
                                            lineColor:'DarkGray',
                                            opposite : false,
                                            maxPadding: 0.2,
                                        labels : {
                                                align : 'right',
                                                x : -5
                                            }
                                    },
                            series : [
                                        {
                                            name : 'Solid Line',
                                            id : 'series1',
                                            data : solid,
                                            allowPointSelect : true,
                                            color : '#888888',
                                            marker: {
                                                enabled: false
                                            }

                                        },
                                        {
                                            name : 'Dashed',
                                            data : dot,
                                            dashStyle : 'dot',
                                            id : 'series2',
                                            color : '#666666',
                                            allowPointSelect : true,
                                            marker: {
                                                enabled: false
                                            }

                                        }
                                    ]
                        });
                        create_div_dynamic(j,'main','main');
                        var main = 'main'+ j;
                        var chartDiv = $('#'+renderCont).children(":first").attr('id');
                        //console.log(chartDiv);
                        create_div_dynamic(j,'title_div','title_div');
                        $('#' + main).append($('#'+ chartDiv));
                        $('#' + renderCont).append($('#'+ main));
                }
            } //End of Each Chart Loop
        }
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body id="mainBody">
</body>
</html>
```

I am posting the sample json in Jsfiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/t95r60fc/

Save this json as json1.json and keep it in same directory as Chart.html and open the html in browser as given below :

[file:///C:/temp/Chart.html?json=C:/temp/json1.json?callback=jsonCallback](http://file:///C:/temp/Chart.html?json=C:/temp/json1.json?callback=jsonCallback)

Final output will be like this : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var envelopBorder =[[-20, 63], [-20, 85], null, null,null,null,[19, 130], [35,150], [60,150],[65,148], [80,140],[80,100],[65,82],[55,70],[40,67],[20,63],[15,63],[-20,63]] ;

var dasshedBorder =[[-20, 85],[-20, 100],[1, 130],[19, 130]] ;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Operating Envelop'
    },
        xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Evaporating Temperature (°F)'
        },

        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineWidth:1,
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Normal',
        data: envelopBorder
    }, {
        name: 'Dash',
        data: dasshedBorder,
        dashStyle: 'dash'
    }]
});
```

Result :-

[jsfiddle.net/7c9929mg](http://jsfiddle.net/7c9929mg/)