# Highcharts: how to use multiple line formats in one series?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to use multiple line formats in a line chart with a single data series, e.g. like this:
[image]

I've created this example by concatenating two separate series, but I'd rather not use this workaround.

Does anyone know how to do this with Highcharts?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300330/highcharts-line-graph-with-half-solid-line-and-half-dotted-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it only by two series.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can use zones against the x-axis on a single series to get multiple line styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-zoneaxis-x/

```
series: [{
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0),
        pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
        zoneAxis: 'x',
        zones: [{
            value: Date.UTC(2015, 5),
            color: colors[2]
        }, {
            value: Date.UTC(2015, 6),
            color: colors[5]
        }, {
            value: Date.UTC(2015, 8),
            color: colors[2]
        }, {
            color: colors[5]
        }]
}]
```

Comment: For me, zones seems to always apply to all series. Even though I've put them in the corresponding data series section.