# Highcharts: How to apply dashStyle to one column of line chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to apply a dotted line to the last column in my Highcharts line graph but I am unable to find a solution.

Here is my Highcharts code:

```
      }
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { year: '%Y' },
        tickInterval: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1) - Date.UTC(2011, 0, 1),
        title: { 
          text: 'Years', style: {color: '#333', fontFamily: 'sans-serif',}
        }
      }
      yAxis: { 
        tickInterval: 5,
        title: { 
          text: 'Points', style: {color: '#333', fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}
        }   
      },
      series: [{
        showInLegend: false
        color: '#000'
        pointInterval: 31557600000
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2005, 0, 1)
        data: [data['points_2005'], data['points_2006'], data['points_2007'], 
        data['points_2008'], data['points_2009'], data['points_2010'], data['points_2011'], 
        data['points_2012'], data['points_2013']]
          }]
```

I have tried to edit the 2013 data point with this code:

```
{data['points_2013'], dashStyle: 'shortdot'}
```

I have attached an image here to explain. [image]

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Code associated with comments below:

```
  series: [
    {
      showInLegend: false
      color: '#79C417'
      pointInterval: 31557600000
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2005, 0, 1)
  pointEnd: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1)
      data: [searchData['points_2005'], searchData['points_2006'], searchData['points_2007'], searchData['points_2008'], searchData['points_2009'], searchData['points_2010'], searchData['points_2011'], searchData['points_2012']]
    }
    {
      showInLegend: false
      color: '#79C417'
      pointInterval: 31557600000
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1)
  pointEnd: Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1)
      dashStyle: 'shortdot'
      data: searchData['points_2013']
    }
```

Comment: you have to create a new series data for dashed line.

Comment: By that do you mean I will have one series with 2005 to 2012 and then another series with one data point for 2013.

Comment: I tried that by copying the series and pasting it below as shown at the bottom of question. However I get an unmatched OUTDENT error.

Comment: you have to define its starting point too. In your case starting point is 2012 and end is 2013.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300330/highcharts-line-graph-with-half-solid-line-and-half-dotted-line Please refer this link.

Comment: I have defined both the start and end points as I have shown above but I am still receiving the Outdent error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: data: [{x: 3, y: PutSomeInt value here}],   Try this it should work X:searchData['points_2012'],Y:searchData['points_2013']